# Property setting works in development machine but not in Build Server

Tags: c#, jenkins, visual-studio-2015

```
public static bool Property1 { get; set; } = true;
```

Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 allows the above setting and compiles with .NET 4.0 as the target platform.

However the build server with no Visual Studio and using Jenkins to compile with .NET 4.0 fails in this line.

It had to be corrected to:

```
public static bool Property1 { get; set; }
```

How can one stop Visual Studio from letting a setting which later breaks the build server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C# 6 you can initialize auto-properties directly and C# 6 language features can be used by the new compiler even in .Net 4. If you use an old compiler it will not be able to compile - that should be your problem.

So set the language features in the settings for *each project*:

```
Properties => Build tab => Advanced button => Language Version
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Property default values is a c# 6.0 construct, which is in .Net 4.6.

VS 2015 Update 2 has .Net 4.6.  Even if you care compiling towards 4.0, it's still using the 4.6 library and the property default value syntax you are using is valid.

In your standalone server, you only have .Net 4.0. Which is c# version 4.0 and does not support default values for properties.

You can continue to compile towards .Net 4.0, however you'll need to add the .Net 4.6 libraries to your build server.

Comment: Is it possible to have my development machine raise an error when compiling?

Comment: If you are using msbuild, you could probably use the "/toolsversion:version " switch to specify .Net 4.6.  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx